# Less POST then GET fields in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a `ModelResource` in Tastypie which exposes a set of fields which I whiltelisted like this: `fields = ["fA", "fB", "fC"]`. The model contains a couple of more fields. Now the question is, how can I have a detail GET method which contains these additional fields `fD`, `fE` and so on but restricting the POST method to the three original fields? Background is the following, the additional fields are for example something like this `added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` and I don't want my API users to have them submit those fields. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as easy as to override the `dehydrate` method, e.g.:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data["fD"] = bundle.obj.fD
    bundle.data["custom_field"] = bundle.obj.custom_field
    return bundle
```

See: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#adding-custom-values